# xcode simulate location gpx time duration?

Tags: ios, xcode, gpx

Is it possible to put a time duration (e.g. 2:00pm - 4:30pm) for a gpx file to simulate location on an iOS device for a specific amount of time?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">

    <wpt lat="41.7264" lon="-73.9339">
        <name>College</name>

    </wpt>

</gpx>
```

If there isn't a way to put an allotted amount of time, is there a way to put a time duration such as 2.5 hrs ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add in wpt

```
<time>2014-09-24T14:55:37Z</time>
```

Comment: So would that be the start time? Is there a way to put an end time?

Comment: when you set time that time to next given time location is given let long.